# Vuejs use NeDB,can not find database files

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nedb

Vue create project：

```
vue init webpack-simple nedbtest
```

install Nedb database：

```
npm i nedb -S
```

change **App.vue** ：

```
<template>
<div>
  <button @click="insert">insertData</button>
  <button @click="find">FindData</button>
</div>
</template>

<script>
  var Datastore = require('nedb')
  var db = new Datastore({filename:'./test.db', autoload:true})
  export default {
    name: 'app',
    methods:{
      insert () {
        db.insert({name:"admin", password:"123"}, function(err, res) {
          console.log(res)
        })
      },
      find () {
        db.find({}, function(err, res) {
          console.log(res)
        })
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

Where is the test.db file？ I can not find this file! I can find this file when use Nodejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is explained in the README that in the browser version, the database is persisted to the best available storage option in the browser, amongst indexedDB, localstorage etc.

You cannot find this file on the hard drive, because browse era would not allow script to create files.

Answer (score 1):

As said [here](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb#browser-version) in the documentation:

> In the browser version, If you specify a filename, the database will be persistent, and
>   automatically select the best storage method available (IndexedDB,
>   WebSQL or localStorage) depending on the browser.

That means that the "filename" must be stored somewhere in either of this method, depending on the browser.

I never used this project, but I suppose that it must give the filename to a DB in indexDB, or to the key of the localStorage value etc...

Comment: Thanks for your answer!